# GridDB :python client multi_putのトラブル

Tags: python, database

GridDB python client (version 0.8)を使用していますが,2つトラブルに見舞われました.
両方共store.multi_putに関することです.

1.引数に存在しないコンテナ名をあたえるとcore dumpしてしまう.
2.複数回のコールでメモリー使用量の増加が見られた. memory leakか?

以上よろしくお願いします.

Answer (score 1):

先日、Troubles in multi_put function のIssueがあり
https://github.com/griddb/python_client/issues/12
で解決済みのようです。